# Total Percentage discount not displayed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We have used the following code to show total percentage discount on categories page products and on single product page. But that code does not show any output. So please review this code and help me if anyone knows the solution.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_price_html', 'woocommerce_custom_sales_price', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_custom_sales_price( $price, $product ) {
  $percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 );
  return $price . sprintf( __('<span class="percentage-dscnt"> %s Off</span>', 'woocommerce' ), $percentage . '%' );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code into your functions.php its currently working for shop page the screenshot here   http://prntscr.com/flgkcx  you can design it according to your need.

```
function woocommerce_saved_sales_price( $price, $product ) {
$sale = isset($product->sale_price) ? $product->sale_price : '';
if(!empty($sale))
{
    $percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 );
    return $price . sprintf( __('%s', 'woocommerce' ), "<div class='sale-perc'>-" . $percentage ."%</div>" );
}else
{
    return $price;
}
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'woocommerce_saved_sales_price', 10, 2 );
```

CSS

```
.sale-perc {
background-color: #D9534F;
display: inline;
padding: .2em .6em .3em;
font-size: 75%;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
border-radius: .25em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay. But i need percentage discount like this -> http://nimb.ws/meoza2

Comment: I have updated the answers please check it it's working for the category page.

Comment: Thanks. Your above edited code work good on shop page. 
See here -> http://nimb.ws/qyWE82   But this code not display Percentage discount on single product page. See here -> http://nimb.ws/4d2XhW 

So can you please know to me How to show percentage discount on single product page also.

Thanks.

Comment: hey please check updated answer replace the code with above which one your last time save in your functions.PHP

Comment: Above replaced code work perfect a s per my requirements.

Thanks.